# ExceptionStackContext for tornado testing async app

Tags: tornado

have watched ajdavis@pycon2015 about testing async apps, as below:
http://pyvideo.org/video/3419/eventually-correct-testing-async-apps

I have a question about the usage of ExceptionStackContext. In the presentation, it's used as below:

```
import unittest
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class TestAsync(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_delay(self):
        io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        def handle_exception(typ, val, tb):
            self.failure = (typ, val, tb)
            io_loop.stop()
        def done():
            self.assertAlmostEqual(time.time() - start, 2)
            self.stop()
        with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exception):
            delay(3, done)  # fail the assert
        io_loop.start()
```

run this test, the io_loop will not stop. because the handle_exception is not called.

my async method `delay` is:

```
import threading
import time

def delay(delay_seconds, callback):
    def wrap():    
        time.sleep(delay_seconds)
        callback()
    t = threading.Thread(target=wrap)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

so i think, it should ExceptionStackContext should wrap the `done()` , as below:

```
def callback():
    with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exception):
        done()
delay(2, callback)
io_loop.start()
```

is this the wright way to use ExceptionStackContext?

by the way, ExceptionStackContext in tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase is useless in fact:

```
def run(self, result=None):
    with ExceptionStackContext(self._handle_exception):
        super(AsyncTestCase, self).run(result)
```

`super(AsyncTestCase, self).run(result)` does not throw up the AssertException.

Comment: add async method ``delay``, which i think is the problem, compared with that from ajdavis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackContexts` are magical: there are many places in Tornado which automatically capture the current `StackContext` and resume it later. So when `delay()` calls `done()` (assuming `delay()` is implemented in terms of `IOLoop.add_timeout` or otherwise handles `StackContext` correctly), the `ExceptionStackContext` has been reestablished.

Similarly, even though the `ExceptionStackContext` in `AsyncTestCase.run()` never directly catches any exceptions, it establishes the "current" `StackContext` to be captured anywhere within the test. (That's why it's `with ExceptionStackContext` instead of an ordinary `try/except`)

Comment: my ``delay()`` is implemented using another Thread, not ``IOLoop.add_timeout``. As a result, when exception happens in the callback method ``done()`` , the exception is not handled by ``StackContext`` . so i have to  make sure the callback method ``done()`` will be handled by StackContext, either by ``stack_context.wrap()`` or running the callback inside another ExceptionStackContext

Comment: Yeah, if you're implementing asynchronous primitives from scratch then you'll have to use `stack_context.wrap` to ensure the context gets propagated.

Comment: BTW, As I grep the tornado code, currently,  ``StackContext`` in ``stack_context.py`` is not used anywhere. Instead ``ExceptionStackContext`` is used, and it seems enough for most cases. is ``StackContext`` designed or reserved for some special cases?  i'm just curious.

Comment: StackContext can be used to provide something like a thread-local variable, but it's not used anywhere in Tornado itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the examples carefully, then ExceptionStackContext works as I claim it does. [It's much easier to follow if you read my article](http://emptysqua.re/blog/eventually-correct-async-testing-tornado/).

You called "self.stop" with a unittest.TestCase, but TestCase doesn't have self.stop, only AsyncTestCase does. To use a TestCase, try:

```
import unittest
import time
from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


def delay(seconds, callback):
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.add_timeout(io_loop.time() + seconds, callback)


class TestAsync(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_delay(self):
        io_loop = IOLoop.current()
        start = time.time()

        def handle_exception(typ, val, tb):
            self.failure = (typ, val, tb)
            io_loop.stop()

        def done():
            self.assertAlmostEqual(time.time() - start, 2, places=1)
            io_loop.stop()

        with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exception):
            delay(3, done)  # fail the assert
        io_loop.start()
```

Note I had to declare "start", which you don't in your code, and set "places=1". This works correctly. Or with AsyncTestCase:

```
import time

from tornado import testing
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


def delay(seconds, callback):
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.add_timeout(io_loop.time() + seconds, callback)


class TestAsync(testing.AsyncTestCase):
    def test_delay(self):
        start = time.time()
        delay(3, self.stop)
        self.wait()
        self.assertAlmostEqual(time.time() - start, 2, places=1)
```

Comment: have re-run this demo with the your async method ``delay()`` , it works as demand.  Then i read the code of ``io_loop.add_timeout`` , it use  ``stack_context.wrap`` to wrap the callback, which i guess is the magic. Thanks for your comment, next time i should browse your blog carefully first.